# VBA Excel Why is my intA is equal to 0 in ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("Y11"))

Tags: excel, vba, formula

```
Sub MySum()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intA As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
intA = Total
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Do While intA > 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("Y11")) 'DBSM
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("G11")) 'DBSC
        ActiveSheet.Range("E" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("P11")) 'OCBCC
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & intA + 2) = Worksheets(intA).Name 'DATE
        intA = intA - 1
    Loop
Next ws
End Sub
```

i dont get why intA equal to 0 when put it in ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intA + 2)

Comment: Are you sure you want to have 2 nested loops? For the first iteration of the `For each`-loop, `intA` is set to the number of sheets (`Total`). Then you enter the inner loop that is executed until `intA` is 0. Now the next iteration of the `For each` starts, but `intA` stays 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @FunThomas' comment your loops seems somewhat strange, but it may just be what you want.

if you want to restart with `intA` being `Total` at each sheet then you could do this:

```
Sub MySum()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intA As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'intA = Total
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    intA = Total 'set 'intA' to the value of 'Total' before the next processing step, 
                 'that way it will be set for each iteration.

    Do While intA > 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("Y11")) 'DBSM
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("G11")) 'DBSC
        ActiveSheet.Range("E" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("P11")) 'OCBCC
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & intA + 2) = Worksheets(intA).Name 'DATE
        intA = intA - 1
    Loop

Next ws
End Sub
```

An alternative code could be (this is more common):

```
Sub MySum()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intA As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'intA = Total
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For intA = Total to 1 step -1 'assuming there is a requirement to count down, as opposed to counting up?
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("Y11")) 'DBSM
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("G11")) 'DBSC
        ActiveSheet.Range("E" & intA + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(intA).Range("P11")) 'OCBCC
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & intA + 2) = Worksheets(intA).Name 'DATE
    Next intA
Next ws
End Sub
```